# Win7-specific UI painting issue in Outlook UserControls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, outlook, vsto

I developed an Outlook 2007 side-bar UserControl that appears on the right side of email windows.

In the case that it is running in a Win7 environment; If the user launches an Email Compose form from another program(like MS Word), the UserControl will **Usually** appear blank. Which is to say that it actually does appear sometimes (about 1/5 probability).

What cases can actually cause a form to not Paint at all anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this also, my workaround is to go userControl.Width++; which seems to force a the paint to happen..